# Dask - Rechunk or array slicing causing large memory usage?

Tags: python, windows, memory, fft, dask

Good afternoon,

I was looking for some help with understanding some excessive (or possibly not) memory usage in my Dask processing chain.

The problem comes from the execution of the following function:

```
def create_fft_arrays(master_array, fft_size, overlap):

    input_shape = master_array.shape[0]
    # Determine zero pad length
    zero_len = fft_size - ((input_shape - fft_size) % ((1-overlap) * fft_size))

    zeros = da.zeros((zero_len, master_array.shape[1]),
                     dtype = master_array.dtype,
                     chunks = (zero_len, master_array.shape[1]))
    # Create the reshaped array
    reshape_array = da.concatenate((master_array, zeros), axis = 0)
    # Create an index series to use to index the reshaped array for re-blocking.
    fft_index = np.arange(0, reshape_array.shape[0] - (fft_size -1), fft_size * overlap)
    # Break reshape_array into fft size chunks
    fft_arrays = [reshape_array[x:x + fft_size] for x in fft_index]

    # Returns list of dask arrays
    return [array.rechunk(array.shape) for array in fft_arrays]
```

Where `master_array` is a `Dask Array` too large to hold in memory (703, 57600001 points in this instance).

**As an minimal example, the following causes the same memory usage as the full code below**

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

def create_fft_arrays(master_array, fft_size, overlap):

    input_shape = master_array.shape[0]
    # Determine zero pad length
    zero_len = fft_size - ((input_shape - fft_size) % ((1-overlap) * fft_size))

    zeros = da.zeros((zero_len, master_array.shape[1]),
                     dtype = master_array.dtype,
                     chunks = (zero_len, master_array.shape[1]))
    # Create the reshaped array
    reshape_array = da.concatenate((master_array, zeros), axis = 0)
    # Create an index series to use to index the reshaped array for re-blocking.
    fft_index = np.arange(0, reshape_array.shape[0] - (fft_size -1), fft_size * overlap)
    # Break reshape_array into fft size chunks
    fft_arrays = [reshape_array[x:x + fft_size] for x in fft_index]

    # Returns list of dask arrays
    return [array.rechunk(array.shape) for array in fft_arrays]

# Fabricate an input array of the same shape and size as the problematic dataset
master_array = da.random.normal(10, 0.1, size = (703, 57600001), chunks = (703, 372))

# Execute the create_fft_arrays function
fft_arrays = create_fft_arrays(master_array.T, 2**15, 0.5)
```

To put the code in context, execution of the following code causes my RAM (20Gb) to max out when executing the last line `fft_arrays = create_fft_arrays(master_array.T, FFT_SIZE, 0.5)`:

```
import dask.array as da

import h5py as h5
import numpy as np

import os

FORMAT = '.h5'
DSET_PATH = '/DAS/Data'
TSET_PATH = '/DAS/Time'

FFT_SIZE = 2**15
OVERLAP = 0.5

input_dir = r'D:\'
file_paths = []

# Get list of all valid files in directory
for dir_name, sub_dir, f_name in os.walk(input_dir):
    for f in f_name:
        if f[-1*len(FORMAT):] == FORMAT:
            file_paths.append(os.path.join(dir_name, f))

#H5 object for each file
file_handles = [h5.File(f_path, 'r') for f_path in file_paths]

# Handle for dataset and timestamps from each file
dset_handles = [f[DSET_PATH] for f in file_handles]
tset_handles = [f[TSET_PATH] for f in file_handles]

# Create a Dask Array object for each dataset and timestamp set
dset_arrays = [da.from_array(dset, chunks = dset.chunks) for dset in dset_handles]
tset_arrays = [da.from_array(tset, chunks = tset.chunks) for tset in tset_handles]

# Concatenate all datasets along along the time axis
master_array = da.concatenate(dset_arrays, axis = 1)

def create_fft_arrays(master_array, fft_size, overlap):

    input_shape = master_array.shape[0]
    # Determine zero pad length
    zero_len = fft_size - ((input_shape - fft_size) % ((1-overlap) * fft_size))

    zeros = da.zeros((zero_len, master_array.shape[1]),
                     dtype = master_array.dtype,
                     chunks = (zero_len, master_array.shape[1]))
    # Create the reshaped array
    reshape_array = da.concatenate((master_array, zeros), axis = 0)
    # Create an index series to use to index the reshaped array for re-blocking.
    fft_index = np.arange(0, reshape_array.shape[0] - (fft_size -1), fft_size * overlap)
    # Break reshape_array into fft size chunks
    fft_arrays = [reshape_array[x:x + fft_size] for x in fft_index]

    # Returns list of dask arrays
    return [array.rechunk(array.shape) for array in fft_arrays]

# Break master_array into FFT sized arrays with a single chunk in each
fft_arrays = create_fft_arrays(master_array.T, FFT_SIZE, 0.5)
```

After this, I would go on to use the `da.fft.fft` method to calculate the frequency response of each of these fft arrays.

Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated,

George

Comment: You will probably get a better response sooner if you are able to produce an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Amended, hopefully that may be a little clearer.

Comment: Going through line by line, this appears to be the line that is using large amounts of memory: `fft_arrays = [reshape_array[x:x + FFT_SIZE] for x in fft_index]`.Is it the slicing operation that is causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your master array has very many chunks

```
>>> master_array = da.random.normal(10, 0.1, size = (703, 57600001), chunks = (703, 372))
>>> master_array.npartitions
154839
```

There is some administrative overhead to each chunk, so it is good to keep the number somewhat smaller than this.  This this [section on chunks](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#chunks) from the [dask.array documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array.html)

Your bottleneck comes about when you try to slice into this array thousands of times.

Your problem might be somewhat resolved by increasing the chunksize.  The document linked to above provides some recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I kicked off with that chunk size as that is the h5 chunk size. Ultimately, data IO from disk will be the bottleneck, but I wanted to experiment with Dask to try to make this workflow scale to run on an EC2 instance. Upping the chunk size for the `master_array` seems to allow me to build the graph at least. Thanks for the help.